# Jquery selecting closest checkbox inbox not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selector, closest

I have a `treelist` containing multiple levels of `checkboxes` and I am trying to get the parent `checkbox` to show as `'checked'` when any of children `checkboxes` are clicked.  For some reason this is not working and it's killing me.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
        $("input.boundChild[type=checkbox]").click(function() {              
            $(this).closest("input.boundParent").prop("checked", "checked");
        });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li class="collapsed expanded">
       <input id="0" class="boundParent" type="checkbox" >
        Australia
             <ul style="display: block;">
               <li>
                  <input id="0/" class="boundChild" type="checkbox" checked="">
                  <input type="hidden" value="Intel Australia PTY Ltd.">
               </li>
             </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`input` elements can't have children, in your markup `input.boundParent` is not one of the parents of the `input.boundChild`. It's a sibling of the `ul` element. you can use `prev` method.

```
$(function() {
    $("input.boundChild[type=checkbox]").click(function() {              
        $(this).closest('ul').prev().prop("checked", this.checked);
        // $('input.boundParent').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhVvN/

Comment: Ya, great explanation. Although, you should preferably use parents() as closest() will include node itself which is useless in this sample.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(this).parent("li.expanded").find("input.boundParent").attr("checked","checked");
```

Provided the parent li always has the `expanded` class when you select a child.